# Not able to get javafx Listview variable height of rows

Tags: java, listview, javafx

```
 view.setCellFactory(lst ->
    new ListCell<AnchorPane>() {
         int k=1;
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(AnchorPane item,boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setPrefHeight(0.0);
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                if(k == 1){
                   setPrefHeight(100.00);
                  k++;
                }
                else{
                      setPrefHeight(10.00);
                }
                setGraphic(item);
            }
        }

    });
```

Setting different height of row by overriding the update Item and passing anchor pane but not getting different height for the rows.

Comment: What is your use-case? What are you expecting to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: i am expecting different heights of rows according to the content  but in my case all the rows are getting the same height.

Comment: Are they all 100 pixels in height? Note that your code will only set the preferred height to 10.0 on the second time a row is updated. Depending on how many items you have and how you interact with the table - this may never happen. Did you mean for the **first row** to be taller?

Comment: i need the row heading to be shorter 10 px and rows to be taller 100 px , therer are more than 4 headings , each heading has its rows which is taller than heading.  ThankYou